# Why does adding in an immediately invoked lambda make my JavaScript code 2x faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, v8, compiler-optimization

I'm optimizing the compiler of a language to JavaScript, and found a very interesting, if not frustrating, case:

```
function add(n,m) {
  return n === 0 ? m : add(n - 1, m) + 1;
};
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  s += add(4000, 4000);
}
console.log(s);
```

It takes `2.3s` to complete on my machine[1]. But if I make a very small change:

```
function add(n,m) {
  return (() => n === 0 ? m : add(n - 1, m) + 1)();
};
var s = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  s += add(4000, 4000);
}
console.log(s);
```

It completes in `1.1s`. Notice the only difference is the addition of an immediately invoked lambda, `(() => ...)()`, around the return of `add`. **Why does this added call make my program two times faster?**

*[1] MacBook Pro 13" 2020, 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7, Node.js v15.3.0*

Comment: I think you'd call that an IIFE, rather than a "ghost lambda call".

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the terminology, I've updated the question.

Comment: Did you run the test multiple times and confirmed that it was not only by a chance? Also, did you try changing the length of iterations?

Comment: Yes, several times. Changing the length of interactions affects the ratio but the IIFE version is always faster. I've not tried other Node.js versions yet.

Comment: This clearly is not a “useless ghost lambda” if it increases the speed of execution. It is an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). The reason the speed increases is because that IIFE creates a closure around that code. SInce you’re executing that function inside a loop, each loop operates in it’s own closure. Why does this work? It allows all 10k calls to the add() method to go onto the stack immediately without waiting for each individual call to be returned.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it looks like you have a sensible explanation but don't get it. What do you mean by "all 10k calls to the add() method go onto the stack immediately"? In both cases we need a growing stack (this function isn't tail-recursive, after all) so I don't see how the IIFE helps.

Comment: The event loop places function calls (frames) for `add()` precisely the same way. The next call cannot be placed onto the stack until the first returns so that the next call can be made. In the second version, using the IIFE allows `add()` to return immediately - where, without the IIFE, the loop must wait for the logic to conclude before being able to return.

Comment: you would see similar results if you removed the IIFE from `add()` and surrounded the call to `add()` with an IIFE for the same reason.

Comment: Interesting, I'm kind-of starting to get it. But in order for the loop to go from i=0 to i=1, it needs to fully compute `s += add(4000,4000)`, no? So it doesn't matter if it returns an IIFE, the second call to `add` won't even start before the first one is fully computed. Or do you mean that the engine will do some kind of loop-lookahead and start computing the `i=1` iteration before the `i=0` is fully computed? If this is really that impactful performance-wise, I'm trying to gain an intuition here to know when/where I'm supposed to add an IIFE to something.

Comment: With the IIFE, `add()` returns a function immediately - without IIFE, `add()` computes a value and then returns. So with an IIFE, the immediately returned function gets called immediately which places it onto the stack immediately - but the loop doesn’t have to wait for the closure to complete where the loop does have to wait for the non-IIFE computation to complete prior to returning. The stack is fast - the looping part is not! The faster one can get onto the stack the faster JavaScript is going to operate.

Comment: "but the loop doesn’t have to wait for the closure to complete" I think that is the only part I don't get. It needs to wait for the closure to complete to add the result to `s`, i.e., to pass through the `s += ...` line. It can't go to the second iteration of the loop without assigning a number to `s`. No?

Comment: Yes - that is a misstatement - I’m out of time, but will try to find a better way to describe.

Comment: It appears to me that you're just seeing a difference in what the JS optimizing compiler decides it can optimize and by how much.  Very slight differences in code can sometimes cause something to be highly optimizable or not.  Compare Firefox and Chrome (different JS engines) and see if you get the same difference.  I would guess not.

Comment: I asked a question awhile ago about why a subclass of an Array was suddenly 10x slower at some operations, including operations that were not affected at all by the subclass.  Someone from the V8 development team answered that my subclass just caused it to fall off some optimization path, not necessarily because it needed to, but one of the conditions for the optimization was violated by having a subclass.   To simplify the testing of some of these optimizations, they often put extensive conditions around when it can be applied.

Comment: I think jfriend00 is correct and the insight allows me to pinpoint my meaning (so thanks). V8 inlines function calls as part of it’s optimization - so when inlining, V8 places the IIFE on the stack as inlined function while the non-IIFE version optimization would place the computation on the stack. When “waiting for the return” vs. 10k (inlined) IIFEs. Hope that’s better.

Comment: Yep I think that is enough, I get the picture. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: V8 developer here. A very interesting discovery! This makes no sense and shouldn't be happening. There's no such thing as "loops don't have to wait for IIFEs"; Randy is probably confusing that with async callbacks / `setTimeout` or the like. My gut feeling agrees with jfriend00 that this is probably hitting some corner case about applicability of optimizations, or optimizer decisions. I'll take a closer look tomorrow and post a detailed answer with my findings.

Comment: @jmrk interesting, thanks for the comment. Let me know if you find any explanation!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interesting! From looking at the code, it seems fairly obvious that the IIFE-wrapped version should be slower, not faster: in every loop iteration, it creates a new function object and calls it (which the optimizing compiler will eventually avoid, but that doesn't kick in right away), so generally just does more work, which *should* be taking more time.

The explanation in this case is inlining.

A bit of background: inlining one function into another (instead of calling it) is one of the standard tricks that optimizing compilers perform in order to achieve better performance. It's a double-edged sword though: on the plus side, it avoids calling overhead, and can often enable further optimizations, such as constant propagation, or elimination of duplicate computation (see below for an example). On the negative side, it causes compilation to take longer (because the compiler does more work), and it causes more code to be generated and stored in memory (because inlining a function effectively duplicates it), and in a dynamic language like JavaScript where optimized code typically relies on guarded assumptions, it increases the risk of one of these assumptions turning out to be wrong and a large amount of optimized code having to be thrown away as a result.

Generally speaking, making perfect inlining decisions (not too much, not too little) requires predicting the future: knowing in advance how often and with which parameters the code will be executed. That is, of course, impossible, so optimizing compilers use various rules/"heuristics" to make guesses about what might be a reasonably good decision.

One rule that V8 currently has is: don't inline recursive calls.

That's why in the simpler version of your code, `add` will not get inlined into itself. The IIFE version essentially has two functions calling each other, which is called "mutual recursion" -- and as it turns out, this simple trick is enough to fool V8's optimizing compiler and make it sidestep its "don't inline recursive calls" rule. Instead, it happily inlines the unnamed lambda into `add`, and `add` into the unnamed lambda, and so on, until its inlining budget runs out after ~30 rounds. (Side note: "how much gets inlined" is one of the somewhat-complex heuristics and in particular takes function size into account, so whatever specific behavior we see here is indeed specific to this situation.)

In this particular scenario, where the involved functions are very small, inlining helps quite a bit because it avoids call overhead. So in this case, inlining gives better performance, even though it is a (disguised) case of recursive inlining, which in general often is bad for performance. And it does come at a cost: in the simple version, the optimizing compiler spends only 3 milliseconds compiling `add`, producing 562 bytes of optimized code for it. In the IIFE version, the compiler spends 30 milliseconds and produces 4318 bytes of optimized code for `add`. That's one reason why it's not as simple as concluding "V8 should always inline more": time and battery consumption for compiling matters, and memory consumption matters too, and what might be acceptable cost (and improve performance significantly) in a simple 10-line demo may well have unacceptable cost (and potentially even cost overall performance) in a 100,000-line app.

---

Now, having understood what's going on, we can get back to the "IIFEs have overhead" intuition, and craft an even faster version:

```
function add(n,m) {
  return add_inner(n, m);
};
function add_inner(n, m) {
  return n === 0 ? m : add(n - 1, m) + 1;
}
```

On my machine, I'm seeing:

- simple version: 1650 ms
- IIFE version: 720 ms
- add_inner version: 460 ms

Of course, if you implement `add(n, m)` simply as `return n + m`, then it terminates in 2 ms -- algorithmic optimization beats anything an optimizing compiler could possibly accomplish :-)

---

Appendix: Example for benefits of optimization. Consider these two functions:

```
function Process(x) {
  return (x ** 2) + InternalDetail(x, 0, 2);
}

function InternalDetail(x, offset, power) {
  return (x + offset) ** power;
}
```

(Obviously, this is silly code; but let's assume it's a simplified version of something that makes sense in practice.)
When executed naively, the following steps happen:

1. evaluate `temp1 = (x ** 2)`
2. call `InternalDetail` with parameters `x`, `0`, `2`
3. evaluate `temp2 = (x + 0)`
4. evaluate `temp3 = temp2 ** 2`
5. return `temp3` to the caller
6. evaluate `temp4 = temp1 + temp3`
7. return `temp4`.

If an optimizing compiler performs inlining, then as a first step it will get:

```
function Process_after_inlining(x) {
  return (x ** 2) + ( (x + 0) ** 2 );
}
```

which allows two simplifications: `x + 0` can be folded to just `x`, and then the `x ** 2` computation occurs twice, so the second occurrence can be replaced by reusing the result from the first:

```
function Process_with_optimizations(x) {
  let temp1 = x ** 2;
  return temp1 + temp1;
}
```

So comparing with the naive execution, we're down to 3 steps from 7:

1. evaluate `temp1 = (x ** 2)`
2. evaluate `temp2 = temp1 + temp1`
3. return `temp2`

I'm not predicting that real-world performance will go from 7 time units to 3 time units; this is just meant to give an intuitive idea of why inlining can help reduce computational load by some amount.
Footnote: to illustrate how tricky all this stuff is, consider that replacing `x + 0` with just `x` is not always possible in JavaScript, even when the compiler knows that `x` is always a number: if `x` happens to be `-0`, then adding `0` to it changes it to `+0`, which may well be observable program behavior ;-)

Comment: Outstanding answer, as always, and +1 for "*algorithmic optimization beats anything an optimizing compiler could possibly accomplish*" alone :-)

Comment: I don't understand however how "*[inlining] increases the risk of one of [guarded] assumptions turning out to be wrong*". Shouldn't inlining a generic function into multiple different monomorphic call sites increase the optimisation potential by allowing closer assumptions, contrasted to making a polymorphic assumption? I would've understood if your sentence argued that "*a large**r** amount of code has to be thrown away [when the guard hits]*" (than the amount of code if it hadn't been inlined).

Comment: Amazing answer! It makes absolute sense now, that the mutual recursion tricks V8 into inlining and unrolling few rounds of the recursion, making it much faster. Very cool, thanks so much for taking your time to investigate this problem and write this detailed answer!

Comment: Can I use this opportunity to ask a small, related question? Is there a plan to ever give an option to disable the stack limit? Right now JS is kinda broken as a functional language, in the sense calls to simple recursive functions (ex: `add(10000,10000)`) fail in practice, and there is no workaround. The V8 is insanely fast, if we had limitless stacks we could use it as an alternative to, say, Chez Scheme, as a viable compile target for functional languages. Right now we need complex global transformations like continuations to compile recursive code to JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi: you can read it in at least two ways: (1) increased risk of having to throw away a large amount of optimized code, because while individual guards are not more likely to fail, the impact is greater when they do; (2) increased risk of having to deopt function A if it inlined B compared to if it didn't inline anything. Not quite sure how to rephrase it to make that clearer...

Comment: @MaiaVictor: operating systems impose limits on the stack consumption of running processes, and simply kill the entire process when it exceeds that limit. V8 throws a `RangeError` when the stack reaches a certain height to prevent that from happening ;-)

Comment: @jmrk ah, fair enough, but then, what about detecting pure functions and doing transformations like tail-call optimization, cps, trampolines? Basically emulate what Scheme does. That should be possible, no? I mean, you guys managed to make strings behave as if [every operation was magically O(1)](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/jszqk7/should_we_try_making_a_string_type_with_js/). I guess avoiding stack overflows should be within the realms of your capabilities (:

Comment: Certainly, tail call optimization is technically possible. It's been done, and then undone (summary: because the ecosystem couldn't agree on how to do it). See e.g. https://v8.dev/blog/modern-javascript#proper-tail-calls and crbug.com/v8/4698#c72.

Comment: But tail-call alone isn't enough (as not every function is easily written tail-recursively). What I'm trying to say is: it would be really really awesome if JS offered a way - any way - to allow recursive algorithms to just work, like in Haskell, Scheme; be it an optimization, or an explicit feature. Other than that, V8 has everything it takes to make JS a great functional language. Hope you guys consider this problem sometime! Thanks so much for all the answers (: